# good book for proof based statistics/econometrics?

Tags: regression, probability, hypothesis-testing, estimation, references

My lecturer has recommended the following books to me:

- Greene, Econometrics Analysis
- Davidson & MacKinnon, Econometric Analysis
- Fumio Hayashi, Econometrics

However, my problem with these books is that they tend to completely gloss over the proofs of statements that they make.

**I am looking for a book that treats concepts like linear regression, (multiple) hypothesis testing, t-distributions, F-distributions, and so forth, on a solid foundation of probability theory, showing in each case how we justify certain methods based on solid probability theory.**

Comment: Take a look at Advanced Econometrics by Takeshi Amemiya, this is the book Hayashi often refers to for the mathematical details.

Comment: I think that Greene, Econometric Analysis, does what you ask ? If I remember well it does not only mention the results, but also gives the proofs ? Do you have a concrete example of something where the proof is missing ?